# Is it possible to transform a string into a list, like this: "man1\nman2\nwoman\nman4" into ["man1", "man2", "man4"] in PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Is it possible to transform a string into a list, like this:

"man1\nman2\nwoman\nman4"

into

["man1", "man2", "man4"]

in python

Comment: string.split("\n")

Comment: It prints like this ['mani1', 'mani2', 'sudha', 'mani4']

Comment: I am looking for this output ["man1", "man2", "man4"]

Comment: `[i for i in "man1\nman2\nwoman\nman4".splitlines() if i.startswith('man')]`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use [string.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split).

```
>>> x = "man1\nman2\nman3"
>>> x.split('\n')
['man1', 'man2', 'man3']
```

Comment: It's correct fore the first half and need for second half. x = "man1\nman2\nwoman\nman4" .. not x = "man1\nman2\nman3"

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

in_str = "man1\nman2\nwoman\nman4"
lst = list(in_str.split("\n"))

out = [x for x in lst if re.search(man, x)]
print out

This prints ["man1", "man2", "man4"]